# Как работают сессии в связке node.js + express

Tags: node.js, сессия, express

Вопрос теоретический, но имеет место быть. 
При написании бота на Node.js столкнулся с необходимостью использовать сессии. Использую `Express`, следовательно и `express-session`. 
Моим клиентом, с точки зрения сервера, всегда будет, например, API Вконтакте. Как я понимаю, для каждого нового сообщения от нового пользователя не будет создаваться новая сессия, а все будет писаться в уже существующую. Правильно ли это? Или у сессий иной механизм определения клиента. И как это можно реализовать с наименьшими потерями?